# get type in withlatestFrom

Tags: redux, rxjs, ngrx

I have the following selector

```
export const featureAdapter: EntityAdapter<IRoute> = createEntityAdapter<IRoute>({
  selectId: model => model.routeId,
});

export interface State extends EntityState<IRoute> {
  selectedRouteId: string;
  selectedPointId: string;
}

export const selectAllEntities: (state: object) => Dictionary<IRoute> = featureAdapter.getSelectors(selectRouteState).selectEntities;

export const selectedR: MemoizedSelector<object, string> = createSelector(selectRouteState, getSelectedRoute);

export const selectedRoute: MemoizedSelector<object, IRoute> = createSelector(
      selectAllEntities,
      selectedR,
      (entities, id) => entities[id]
    );
```

that return something of type `IRoute`

In my effect I use a withlatest from

```
  onAction$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.onAction>(featureActions.ActionTypes.onAction),
    concatMap(action =>
      of(action).pipe(
        withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(select(RoutesStoreSelectors.getById(), {routeId: action.payload.routeId}))),
      )
    ),
    switchMap(([action, route]) => {})
 )
```

inside the

```
switchMap(([action, route])
```

the route variable, is of type any. but it should be of type `IRoute`

how can I make it work correctly ?

Answer (score 2):

I can't see why TypeScript cannot infer the type, but you can always explicitly specify the type.

```
  onAction$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.onAction>(featureActions.ActionTypes.onAction),
    concatMap(action =>
      of(action).pipe(
        withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(select(RoutesStoreSelectors.getById(), {routeId: action.payload.routeId}))),
      )
    ),
    switchMap(([action, route]: [Action, IRoute]) => {})
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you need get hold of dispatched `action` in `switchMap`, but you can do the following to get the `route` of type `IRoute` -

```
onAction$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.onAction>(featureActions.ActionTypes.onAction),
    switchMap(action =>
      combineLatest(of(action), this.store$.pipe(select(RoutesStoreSelectors.getById(), {routeId: action.payload.routeId})))
    ),
    switchMap(([action, route]) => {})
 )
```

Having code like this will ensure to have the `action` of type of the dispatched action and `route` is of type `IRoute`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried, but route is still of type any.

And for the question why I hold the action inside my switchMap, is because I need some value that are in the action.payload to pass them as parameter inside my effect dispatched action. (I remove the code for the exemple because it would make the post less readable

Comment: @Bobby then you should pass the action.payload instead of all action but it is up to you and as per your design. Back to the issue - Are you sure that in your selector ‘entities[id]’ returns value of type IRoute, it does not matter what is in you type of selector I mean memoizedselector<>.

Comment: Pls watch the edit, I think so, I mean, the value I get is definitely a IRoute, and I think my declarations are correct so the compiler should find the correct type.